# Insert same values for multiple records based on list of ids

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, unnest

I have a PostgreSQL database and want to insert the same value for multiple records based on record IDs I have.
Is there a way to make a `WHERE` condition in the `INSERT` statement? For example:

```
insert into Customers (new-customer) values ('t') where customer_id in (list)
```

Comment: Do you want to update existing records?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you give a real example please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like:

```
INSERT INTO customers(customer_id, customer_name)
    select  13524, 'a customer name'
where  13524 = ANY ('{13524,5578,79654,5920}'::BIGINT[])
```

Here, a customer with id: `13524` will be added because it's ID is in the list: `{13524,5578,79654,5920}`

I hope that what you are looking for!

Answer (score 5):

To insert a row for every id in your list, you can use [`unnest()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) to produce a set of rows:

```
INSERT INTO customers(customer_id, column1)
SELECT id, 't'
FROM   unnest ('{123,456,789}'::int[]) id;
```

If you misspoke and actually meant to `UPDATE` existing rows:

```
UPDATE customers
SET    column1 = 't'
WHERE  customer_id = ANY ('{123,456,789}'::int[]);
```

Comment: Minor syntax error: use "::int[]" to cast the datatype.

Comment: @pkExec: Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

To do it without a `SELECT`, you can use `ARRAY[]` after `unnest()`:

```
INSERT INTO customers (customer_id, column1)
VALUES (unnest(ARRAY[123,456,789]),'t');
```